# The intensity of the insert operation in a table of MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, crud

I need to know **how many** INSERT operations occur per second for a table.

I've tried to get some scripts from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017  but there is nothing to help with.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the count of rows inserted or `insert` statements executed? For any particular second or do you want to be able to look back to any second within some historical range?

Comment: @HABO Hi, bro! Yeah I need calculate rows inserted for last 1 minute or second for instance. Basically I want to track the amount of inserted rows.

Comment: If you can add a createDate column with a data type of `DateTime2` and a default value of `SysDateTime()` then you wouldn't need to track data changes. Just saying.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Adding a `createDate` column doesn't account for any rows that may be deleted. A trigger on inserts could log the date/time and number of rows to a separate table for later analysis. The OP makes no mention of identifying which rows were inserted at any given time, just the rate over some period.

Comment: @HABO That's a good point.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I cannot do it because my table has 1 300 000 000 records of geo positions. The database is big already. Is any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found this script to get count of records. So if execute this script periodically  we can build diagram like time/record cound per table.

```
 SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName, 
    p.rows AS RowCounts,  
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows  
  ORDER BY     RowCounts desc
```